# mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysql-real-escape-string

.../general.php on line 10

Hello, this is my error, but only occurs when I upload my web to a host, in the localhost run well.

the (return mysqli_real_esc..)line is the "line 10".

```html
$conncet = mysqli_connect('xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx');
function array_sanitize(&$datos) {
  global $connect;
  $datos = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$datos);
}
```

thanks for your time!!

Comment: Your $connect variable is probably NULL. Look where you made the connection to the database and check if that part is correct. Did you enter the correct username/password/host combination?

Comment: `$conncet` != `$connect`

Comment: If you were running with error_reporting and display_errors enabled, you'd have been told about your undefined variable. Those settings should NEVER be off on a devel/debug system.

Comment: Thanks!! jajajaja my error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you have typo in your variable, please check your $connect => $conncet variable

```html
$conncet = mysqli_connect('xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx');
function array_sanitize(&$datos) {
  global $connect;
  $datos = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$datos);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You misspelt connect in your initialization. You spelt it conncet. The only reason I can think for that running well on localhost is if errors are set not to show.

Answer (score 0):

first off there is a spelling error on your first line "$conncet" should be $connect

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that your credentials(username & password) is wrong on the web. Find your username and password for the online database.